# How do I prove: Let n ∈ N+. Let m ∈ N+. m<n. Prove that n⊥m ⇒ (n−m)⊥ m.

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

I don't even know how to start, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by $\perp$ in this context?

Comment: N+ is redundant.

Comment: @Jossie Not really. Many people use $\Bbb{N}$ to represent a set including $0$, so the $+$ is necessary to indicate that $n \ne 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We show that if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $n-m$ and $m$ are relatively prime.

Suppose to the contrary that $n-m$ and $m$ are not relatively prime. Then some $d\gt 1$ divides both $n-m$ and $m$. But then $d$ divides $m$ and $(n-m)+m=n$, contradicting the fact that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: How does (n - m) + m = n part come into the proof?

Comment: We want to use the (assumed) fact that $d$ divides $n-m$ and $m$ to conclude that $d$ divides $n$. Recall that if $d$ divides $a$ and $b$, then $d$ divides the sum $a+b$. So if $d$ divides $n-m$ and $m$, then $d$ divides the sum $(n-m)+m$, which is $n$.